# Is it bad practice to make a method package or private for the sake of testing?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

In Java (in an Android specific context, but this should apply across the board), is it considered bad practice to remove a `private` modifier - and thus be `package` specific - for the sake of unit testing?

Say I have something like the following:

```
public void init(long id) {
    mId = id;
    loadItems(1);
}

public void refresh() {
    loadItems(mId);
}

private void loadItems(int page) {
    // ... do stuff
}
```

In this case, I have 2 public methods that should definitely be tested. The concern is that both the `refresh()` and `init()` methods are almost identical minus some logic around handling the id.

It seems like it'd be easiest to write a unit test for `loadItems()` and then just verify that both `init()` and `refresh()` call `loadItems()` with the appropriate id (using something like Mockito). There's not a "good way" to test private methods though.

Would doing that make me a bad software developer? I know private methods technically shouldn't need unit tests, but this would be a straightforward testing approach, IMO, especially if `loadItems()` is somewhat complex.

Comment: Perhaps your current class violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)? For example, you could make a dedicated `ItemsLoader` class which you can test, and inject a (mock) instance of this class into your current class. I'm missing a bit of context though to be more precise.

Comment: Hm... I guess the follow up question might be "when is creating a new class overkill?" which obviously is a bit vague. You and @kha are essentially recommending the same thing.

Comment: +1. Perhaps (I'm not sure) if you could form that into a proper question, it might fit on [Programmers SE](programmers.stackexchange.com). Don't forget to try out the search function first though :)

Comment: @NiekHaarman haha I will be sure to do so. I can't imagine that I'd be the first person to ask that question. It's a little bit more of a concern in the context I'm using it in (mobile... more limited resources), but still not very unique. Thanks!

Comment: @loeschg This was a conflicting point in companies I worked at. Some said that if methods to test are private, they shouldn't be in this class. Some just employed a testing framework that allows to test private methods. But changing visibility level is quite bad - a method that was never designed to be in a public contract suddenly is. The general agreement on Programmers is that you don't test private methods.

Comment: On [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131177052) you can found few chapters about that topic. Sure there are some trade off, but that is a tool in your toolbox.

Comment: The first think that you should ask to yourself when you would like to test a private method is *why it is private?*. You have 99% chances to answer *because should be in an other class*. So, make it protected, test it, do your refactoring  to extract it in a new class and create a private collaborator in the original class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aksed *"Would doing that make me a bad software developer?"*.

I don't think it makes you a bad developer. If you look at .NET for example, they even have a way to allow other libraries to see the internals of another library for the purpose of unit testing (`InternalsVisibleTo`).

I am personally against testing private methods though. In my opinion unit testing should be done on visible methods and not private methods. Testing private methods kind of defeats the point of encapsulation and making a method more visible than it needs to be just for the sake of unit testing looks wrong to me.

If I were you, I would instead test both my public methods. Today, your two methods are almost identical and it's easier to test your private method by making it package visible. Tomorrow however, that may no longer be the case. As both methods are public and easily accessible to other classes, you may be testing the wrong thing if such a scenario happens and the two drift apart.

Better yet (and this is what I would recommend) is to move

```
private void loadItems(int page) {
    // ... do stuff
}
```

to its own class with its own interface and then test `loadItems(int page)` once using a separate unit test and then test the two public methods by just making sure they call the interface with the arguments you're expecting. This way, you're testing your entire code and avoid the pitfall I explained above.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it is better to have tests than not to, if it makes the code better and easier to maintain I think its a good idea.

I also agree with Niek above re putting the logic in another class.

I would also add that the method is void, and so has side effects which I think are harder to test than simply asserting a returned value.

Perhaps consider something like

List loadItems(int page)

Then check the list returned.